# Increment column value if duplicate value found

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very simple script that imports a CSV of Postcodes and creates a row in a table with it.

I also have a column to store the `total` number of times that Postcode appears in the CSV file.

**Is it possible to increment a column value if a duplicate postcode is found?**

So, if there's 2 instances of **w1a 1aa** it would increment the value in the total column. For example:

```
id | postcode   | total
0  |  w1a 1aa   | 2
1  |  g74 1bc   | 1
2  |  ml10 6qd  | 1
```

---

**Table:**

```
id | postcode | total
```

**PHP:**

```
// connect to db
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "postcodes";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

foreach($csv as $row) {

    $postcode = $row[0];

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO postcodes VALUES (NULL, "'.$postcode.'", 1)';

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}
```

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL allows you to phrase something like the following (can't check syntax right now, but you will find it well documented in the internet):

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
```

This means, attempt to insert a row into a table that has a specific column(s) as unique keys and, if a row exists with the same value of key, it executes the update part.

So, if you define the column **post code** as a unique index, the above construct will do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed response with this - I shall award a green tick shortly :-)

Comment: You are welcome and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do a select first to check if the postcode you are about to enter already exists, if so get the count and update it against that postcode.

Comment: if you have concurrent requests, this is not safe.

Comment: None of OPs code is safe. This is a suggestion for OP to go and learn!

Comment: @Stuart Thank you. I realise it's not production ready at this stage - thanks for your input :)

Comment: @Stuart Greatly appreciate your help here, Stuart - I will be very careful when it comes to securing any data input from CSV to my SQL db :)

Comment: All good @michaelmcgurk - The solution by FDavidov  is far superior!