# Column that increments it's value for each time a value is found in first column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, mariadb

I would like to create a column that increments each time the same value is found in the first column.  These fields could be strings, or integers. Something like:

```
field1 | field2
cat | 1
fish | 1
dog | 1
cat | 2
fish | 2
cow | 1
```

My question is similar to these two ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722795/increment-column-value-if-duplicate-value-found)), ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update)), but I do not want to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` if the key already exists. I want to delete the second record.  So, something like `DELETE FROM t1 WHERE field2 > 1`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107167/mysql-delete-duplicate-records-but-keep-latest) ([MySQL delete duplicate records but keep latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107167/mysql-delete-duplicate-records-but-keep-latest)) is MOST similar to what I'm trying to do, except instead of having an integer auto-incremented ID column, I have another field called `filename`, which would be different for each repeated field1.

Is this called an aggregate function?
How to accomplish this?

Comment: Every time *which* value is found.  Also, you seem to be assuming an ordering of the rows but tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: `row_number() over (partition by field1 order by whatever)`

Comment: Each time the value in `field1` is found set the value of `field2` to be incremented by 1 from the last time the `field1` value was found.  The fields may be strings or whatever, it's not ordered, I understand that.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB 5.5.  So, row_number() is not available.

Comment: write an insert tirgger that get the last number and increments it before inserting

Comment: I'm not inserting data into the database.  I'm attempting to write a delete statement that deletes the duplicates.

Comment: Can't you alter the table ? And after deleting duplicates revert the alter to its original structure ?

Comment: Seem this simulation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issue_2_column_pk

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be asking for is counting a particular value.  So, if you are trying to count `1` values *and* you have an ordering column, then:

```
select t.*, sum(field1 = 1) over (order by <ordering column>) as field2
from t;
```

However, your results suggests that you just want an enumeration of each independent value.  That would be:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by field1 order by <ordering column>) as field2
from t;
```

Comment: I can't use row_number() since I'm on MariaDB 5.5.

Comment: I'm not trying to simply get the count of times that value is present such as `SELECT field1, count(*) as field2 FROM t1 GROUP BY field1 HAVING field2 > 1 ORDER BY field2 DESC`.  I can edit the example above to include a better.

Comment: I Googled the term `ordering column SQL` and found no references to this structure.  Do you have a link to explain what that is?